# Can consistent proxi-finite extensions of ZFC be additive?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

The definition of "strongly coming from $HF$" is given in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3589545/is-proxi-finiteness-stronger-than-its-failure) posting.

Question: if $\varphi, \psi$ each is strongly coming from $HF$, then can the following be true?

$Con (ZFC + \varphi) \land Con (ZFC + \psi) \to Con (ZFC + \varphi + \psi)$

Comment: Let $\phi$ state "all recursive theories extending ZFC are inconsistent" and let $\psi$ be $\neg\phi$.  Then I think both fit the definition and are consistent with ZFC, assuming Con(ZFC).

Comment: @MonroeEskew, I don't see how $\phi$ qualify as strongly coming from $HF$?

Comment: Oh I thought you removed quantifiers are replaced them with existentials.  So you're essentially asking if ZFC is consistent with all sentences that are true in HF.  Well assuming there is a transitive model of ZFC, then yes.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, my definition is more precise than just all sentences that are true in HF, its known that ZFC is inconsistent with all of those, I'm asking if ZFC is consistent with all sentences that are STRONGLY COMING form HF. There is a difference. In the first case take $\forall x (x \text{ is infinite} \to \phi)$ this is trivially true in $HF$ and the same sentence but with $\neg \phi$ in the consequent is also true in $HF$, but we cannot add both to ZFC. I hoped for the *strongly coming* feature to overcome this?